# jQuery compatibility with jQuery UI - getClientRects is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the latest jQuery 3.7.0 and the latest jQuery UI 1.13.2. I am getting an error - `getClientRects is not a function`. Additionally there is also an uncaught `TypeError: Class constructor p cannot be invoked without 'new'` .

Lower jQuery UI version has a known incompatibility with jQuery 3.x, but that issue from years back. But I cannot find anything about this when both are latest.

Comment: Show example code that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack OVerflow. Please provide a [mcve].